Fedora Failed Installation
I am trouble shooting a fedora installation. On board barebones equipped with the trusted platform module. The warnings I receive are a makeup of inoperable writes onto disks. How do I prepare my personal computer hard disks to be converted to fedora? superseding the trusted platform controls
